# Remove multiple empty lines with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, lines

How to remove multiple empty lines with Notepad++ and convert those empty lines with one empty line?

I don't want to remove single empty line but if there are many empty lines (like 5 empty lines) and replace those many empty lines with a one single empty line.

Comment: Off topic for this site, which is about programming.

Comment: You can use a regular expression in the search and replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight and backspace or right click and cut I believe is the only way.
Yours in coding,
Aymen